Is there a way to play Spotify and YouTube podcasts on Google Nest without letting them earn ad revenue?
I want to listen to podcasts at night with voice commands. The Home app only lets me select YTM or Spoofy as my default. Is there a roundabout way not to give either ad revenue?

yes there is ... get an ad free paid subscription
